# document.location enacted after subsequent code

Tags: javascript, ajax

Hello lovely people of StackOverflow.

I'm trying to create a dynamic page using JavaScript AJAX and PHP.

I have created a list of images which have unique ids numbers 1-12. When one is clicked it should pass that id onto a function which changes the page, then uses the id number to load in content to the new page.

My problem is that when I use document.location to change the page (or window.assign) it does not change the page before enacting the following code which loads in the content. Therefore it tries to load the content to a div which doesn't exist on the current page, then changes the page. Does anybody know why this is? And how I can solve it?

I have tried putting the document.location and innerHTML code in separate functions, but the next function is still called before the page changes. I have also tried putting an if statement ahead of the content load but that is also called before the page changes.

Here is my code:

```
    function output (bookList){
         for (var i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {  
         document.getElementById("insertBooksHere").innerHTML += "<ul class=\"bookItem\">";
            for (var t = 0; t<position.length; t++){ 

                if (t==position.length-1)
                        {
                            x = bookList[i][0];
                            document.getElementById("insertBooksHere").innerHTML += "<img class=\'books\'  id = \'" + x + "\' src=\'" +bookList[i][t]+ "\' onClick=\'getBookDetails("+ x +")\'>";
                        }
                        else 
                if ( t == 1 || t==2){   
                        document.getElementById("insertBooksHere").innerHTML += "<li>"+bookList[i][t]+"</li>";
                        }
            }
        document.getElementById("insertBooksHere").innerHTML += "</ul></div>";
    }
    }


    function getBookDetails(id){
        bookID = id;    
        for ( var t = 0; t<12; t++)
        {
        bookDetails[t] = bookList[bookID-1][t];//grab details about specified book from array using x as the value for i.
        }
        loadBookPage(bookID, bookDetails)
    }


function loadBookPage(bookID, bookDetails){
    console.log(window.location.href);
}


function loadBookDetails(){
if ( document.location == 'books/'+bookID+'.php')
{
        x = bookID;
    console.log(bookDetails);
         document.getElementById("book").innerHTML += "<ul class=\"bookItem\">";

        for (var t = 0; t<position.length; t++){ 

            if (t==position.length-1)
                    {
                        document.getElementById("book").innerHTML += "<img class=\'books\' id = \'" + x + "\' src=\'" +bookDetails[t]+ "\'>";

                    }
                    else {  
                    document.getElementById("book").innerHTML += "<li>"+bookDetails[t]+"</li>";
                    console.log("for loop");
                    }
        console.log(bookDetails[t]);
        }
    document.getElementById("book").innerHTML += "</ul>";
    document.getElementById("book").innerHTML += "HELLO!!!";
    }
}
```

And you can see my work here: http://itsuite.it.brighton.ac.uk/rlr17/bookClub/home.php

Thanks guys! Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My problem is that when I use document.location to change the page (or window.assign) it does not change the page before enacting the following code which loads in the content.

That is how JavaScript (when running client side, embedded in a webpage) works.

It runs *in that page*.

If the page goes away (because you loaded a new page) then its execution environment goes away and it stops running.

If you want to do something *in the next page* then you have to pass some data to that page and have code *in the new page* read that data and act on it.

Ideally, you would do this using server side code (as [it is more reliable](http://kryogenix.org/code/browser/everyonehasjs.html), and rarely has an additional runtime cost when you are loading a new page anyway).

Comment: Oh so use PHP POST to send the variables to the next page? Of course! Thanks for your quick response :)